# Expression of theorem by $p\Rightarrow q$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, logic

**$\sqrt 2$ is irrational.**
Is it true that i express this theorem in this way?:
If $\sqrt 2$ is a real number, then it is irrational.
Is there any better way to express this theorem by $p\Rightarrow q$?

Comment: $\sqrt 2$ is a real, irrational number. I think this is better.

Comment: @dREaM: Your statement is not like $p\Rightarrow q$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is a valid statement, and one that can be proven. However, if your assignment was to express "$\sqrt2$ is irrational" as a $p\implies q$ statement, then this is, in my opinion, better: "If $x$ is a positive number such that $x^2 = 2$, then $x$ is irrational."

Comment: I agree with you!

Comment: However it is better that you say: "If x is a positive $real$ number..." .

Comment: @2000 This way you can make almost any statement into that form. For instance, if the theorem says "The specific number / set / function / whatever $z$ has this and this property", then it can be rephrazed as "If $x$ is such that (whatever is needed to ensure that $x$ is, in fact, $z$), then $x$ has this and this specific property". And yes, technically it is better to add positive, _real_ number.